# Trigger method once every day

Tags: java

I'm looking to trigger a method once every day. I've tried scheduling this with Timer and TimerTask, but my problem is that the program may be run several times a day, and somedays maybe none. How can I when the program first starts check if the method already has been run that day?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to store state somewhere external to the program to record whether the action has already been taken that day. Have you looked at how this can be done?

Comment: yeah, i guess i can save the information in a text file and read of that text file everytime the program starts to check if it's been run that day. Just seemed kind of complicated to a simple problem, was curious if there was an easier way. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use cron job with scheduling your selected method

For example  0 20 ***  this do every day clock when 20:00

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the Java Date Class. That way you can save the last time your program was run in a file and then once it is run again read the current date and see if the day changed.

Comment: The `java.util.Date` class is terrible, and should be avoided. It was supplanted years ago by the *java.time.Instant` class.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Quartz Scheduler in the past: https://quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring, there are good abstractions to trigger a method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
}
```

I would suggest using a database to synchronize daily runs between multiple instances of your app:

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * MON-FRI")
public void doSomething() {
    Connection conn = ...
    String sql= "select lastrun from runs where method = 'doSomething' for update";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        if(rs.getDate(1)/* is more than 23 hours ago*/){
            //do your work here....
            rs.updateDate(1, new Date());
            rs.updateRow();
        }
    } else{
        //todo
    }
    //todo: make sure rs, ps, and conn get closed...
}
```

Sources: http://blog.udby.com/archives/15 and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support